# `useAnimatedStyle` was used without a dependency array or Babel plugin. Please explicitly pass a dependency array, or enable the Babel/SWC plugin

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-reanimated

I have tried to add this in the bable file too

```
module.exports = {
   presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
   ],
   plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
   ],
};
```

Is there any other way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. While working with Drawer Navigator,

Then I added the dependency `"react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",`

Then I added the plugins in babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
};
```

Then closed the metro server and cleared the cache using this command

I am using react native cli -> So cleared the cache using this command

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

And I've runned again the command then it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the lower version for the **react-native-reanimated** package

Then add the below line in the **android/build.gradlew** file before the **allProjects**.

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    if(project['name'] == 'react-native-reanimated'){
        project.configurations { compile { } }
    }
}
```

And remove the plugin from the **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
 presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

It worked for me.